# Only display one paragraph of text

Tags: perl, facebook, content-management-system, movabletype

You can set what the Facebook Share preview says. I would like it to be the first paragraph of my movable type entry. The people who make entries sometimes use

```
<p>
```

tags or they use the rich editor which puts in two

```
<br /><br />
```

tags to separate paragraphs.

Is there a way I can have movable type detect when the first paragraph end and only display the first paragraph? I would like to add that to my entry template so it will add some information to my head.

Answer (score 1):

EntryBody has a lot of attributes to help format the output of the tag. You can use those to change the content so it shows up correctly in HTML, JavaScript, PHP, XML or other forms of output.

If you understand how to use regular expressions, you can use that and an additional language, say PHP, to break the body up into an array and only output the first paragraph or element of the array.

The simplest thing, though, I would think, would be to do something like

```
<mt:EntryBody words=100>
```

That will cut off the entry body after the first 100 words. You could also require users to upload an excerpt with the entry and use the entry excerpt for Facebook, instead.